# No sound with speaker on an iMac

Tags: sound, mac

I have an iMac with Snow Leopard and Ubuntu 11.10 installed.

The sound with Snow Leopard works fine and before it worked equally well with Ubuntu but suddenly no longer works with the speaker but when I put the headphones I have the sounds.
Perhaps because of updating Ubuntu?

Can you tell me how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had sound problems on my Mac, too.  I used the following command and it worked:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=imac24' >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

I found this on the [Ubuntu Help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Macmini4-1/Maverick#Sound).  You can also find instructions for fixing sound on Macs on this [other Ubuntu Help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac#Sound).